# C++ vectorizing a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, vectorization

I have some code that uses a `vector<vector<>>` to store calculation results.

Through benchmarking, I have found that this is preventing my code from vectorizing, even though I am accessing the elements with the appropriate C-stride.

I am trying to come up with a data structure that will vectorize and improve my code's performance.

I read a few posts on here, and several of them mentioned creating a class that has 2 separate vectors inside: 1 for storing the data contiguously, and another for storing indices marking the beginning of a new column/row from the original 2D `vector<vector>`.  Essentially, it would decompose the 2D array into a 1D, and use the "helper" vector to allow for proper indexing.

My concern is that I have also read that vectorization doesn't usually happen with indirect indexing like this, such as in common compressed row storage scheme for sparse matrices.

Before I go through all the work of implementing this, has anybody run into this problem before and solved it?  Any other suggestions or resources that could help?

Comment: What do you mean by "... accessing the elements with the appropriate C-stride"? I cannot imagine how you could define a stride for a `vector<vector<T>>`.

Comment: @anatolyg I was just wondering the same. However, I have no idea what a C-stride would be in general

Comment: By C-stride, I mean iterating over the second index, and then the first. So I am basically iterating over all elements of one of the inner vectors before moving on to the next one.  Since vector data is contiguous in memory, and since I am looping over all elements in order, I should get vectorization, but I am not.  I added the stride comment because several posts I read had people looping incorrectly and taking one element from each inner vector, which really screwed up their cache loading. I wanted to avoid people giving that type of answer because it doesn't apply to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small matrix class based on `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class MyMatrix {
    public:

    typedef T value_type;
    struct RowPointer {
        int row_index;
        MyMatrix* parent;
        RowPointer(int r,MyMatrix* p) : row_index(r),parent(p) {}
        T& operator[](int col_index) { 
            return parent->values[row_index*parent->cols+col_index];
        }
    };
    MyMatrix() : rows(0),cols(0),size(0),values(){}
    MyMatrix(int r,int c) : rows(r),cols(c),size(r*c),values(std::vector<T>(size)){}
    RowPointer operator[](int row_index){return RowPointer(row_index,this);}

    private:

    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    size_t size;
    std::vector<T> values;
};
```

It can be used like this:

```
MyMatrix<double> mat = MyMatrix<double>(4,6);
mat[1][2] = 3;
std::cout << mat[0][0] << " " << mat[1][2] << std::endl;
```

It still misses lots of stuff, but I think it is enough to illustrate the idea of flattening the matrix. From your question it was not 100% clear, if your rows have different sizes, then the access pattern is a little bit more complicated.

PS: I dont want to change the answer anymore, but I would never use a `std::vector` to construct a matrix again. Vectors offer flexibility that is not required for a matrix, which usually has same and fixed number of entries in each row.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very good starting point, and when I ran your class on my test problem, I achieved vectorization!